# Can't decrypt luks encrypted partition at boot anymore

Tags: boot, grub2

When I start my computer, Ubuntu loads and finds my encrypted partition and is asking for my encryption passphrase. If I enter the correct encryption passphrase, it fails as if the encryption passphrase wasn't correct.

I can enter ubuntu from a live USB stick, open the disks window, click on the encrypted partition and unlock it there without any troubles.

This happened after I tried to fix a problem with grub where grub wasn't found. Fixing the grub issue involved running vgimportclone and vgchange -ay which created ubuntu-vg11.

Probably this is not enough information to identify the problem, so I would be happy to provide more information if anyone has an idea on how to investigate the issue.

Comment: Please edit your question and include all of the details and specifics about the actions that caused the problem.

Comment: Make sure you don't have a different language selected at boot. That is, if you have multiple language keyboard layouts like English and Russian.

Comment: It's confusing if your use of the term "password" refers to *login password* or to *encryption passphrase*. Or perhaps both at different times.

Comment: To clarify: with "password" i was referring to the encryption passphrase. The passphrase only contains letters that are identical on both german and english keyboard layouts.

Comment: Hi @Nik, it looks like you might want to merge your two accounts. You can find out how to do that here: https://askubuntu.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: When you boot from USB stick and successfully open an encrypted partition, is that partition your boot partition? To be able to better understand your situation, it would be good to know your partition layout, which partitions are LUKS encrypted, and which LUKS partitions you can access via USB live system.